# How to expose a C structure from C library to R with Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to expose a C structure from a C library into R. For example:

```
struct A {
    int flag;
    // ...
}
```

It is common that the library provides API to construct and destroy `A`:

```
A* initA();
void freeA(A* a);
```

Thanks for `RCPP_MODULE`, It is easy to expose it without considering destructor:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(A)

RCPP_MODULE(A) {
  class_<A>("A")
  .field("flag", &A::flag)
  ;
}

//'@export
//[[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP init() {
  BEGIN_RCPP
  return wrap(*initA());
  END_RCPP
}
```

I like this approach, but it might cause memory leak because it does not destruct `A` properly during garbage collection. Adding `.finalizer(freeA)` in `RCPP_MODULE` will cause an error of `free` twice.

Using `XPtr<A, freeA>` might be a solution, but I need to manually define functions to expose `A.flag`.

In general, how do you expose C structure from C library into R with Rcpp?

Comment: there is a mailing list for Rcpp http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/mailman/listinfo/rcpp-devel for non-trivial questions you should ask there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you turn your C struct into a C++ class which allows you allocate in the constructor and free in the destructor.

You can still use different ways to have the class transfer easily between R and C++ --- Modules is one of several possibilities.

Comment: I agree. I tried this approach today.

Care about the copy constructor because `RCPP_MODULE` calls it during constructing the object. It costed me about 30 minutes to debug.

Comment: You do not have to use Modules. If you want more control, just write functions, say, `createInstance()` and `accessInstance()`  --- but Modules can help.  In any event, you will have to translate your data structure into something you can represent as a SEXP -- be iexplicitly or implicitly via Rcpp converters.