# Exposing a C object from an external C library from C++ to R and back again using Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

This is a follow-up question on this one: [Exposing a C struct with Rcpp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58148581/exposing-a-c-struct-with-rcpp)

@DirkEddelbuettel justly criticized that aforementioned question as being too broad in scope so I am here trying to be more specific in my goals, while providing some actual code exemplifying my attempt at this problem.

### Description of the problem

**First thing**: please note that I use (somewhat unfortunately, I will change it eventually) two similar names in my code: `GLuint` and `Gluint`.

I'm trying to wrap this C OpenGL functionality in R (taken from here: [OpenGL 
Textures objects and parameters](https://open.gl/textures)):

```
GLuint tex;
glGenTextures(1, &tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
```

### Approach

I am using Rcpp to achieve these goals:

1. Provide a way of allocating the `Gluint` object from R; perhaps by instantiating an S4 object that wraps the C object (`GLuint` tex) inside?
2. Then, have an R exposed function named `gl_gen_textures` that takes an integer and that object mentioned in 1. Internally, this function `gl_gen_textures` accesses the memory address of the `GLuint` C object and passes it on to `glGenTextures` (C library function).
3. Eventually provide a way of destroying the `Gluint` object created in R and along with it the internal `GLuint` C object.

### Actual code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
using namespace Rcpp;


class Gluint {
public:
  Gluint() {}
  GLuint obj;
};

RCPP_MODULE(gluint_module) {
  class_<Gluint>("Gluint")
  .constructor()
  .field("obj", &Gluint::obj)
  ;
}

//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void gl_gen_textures(unsigned int n, Gluint& tex) {

  uint32_t _n;
  _n = (uint32_t) n; // Convert unsigned int to uint32_t.
  glGenTextures((GLsizei) _n, &(tex.obj));

}
```

### Errors

Currently this code does not compile. I'm getting these errors:

[image]

And here's a snippet of the function `gl_gen_textures` as generated in Rcpp::Exports.cpp lines 136-146:

```
// gl_gen_textures
void gl_gen_textures(unsigned int n, Gluint& tex);
RcppExport SEXP _glfw_gl_gen_textures(SEXP nSEXP, SEXP texSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RNGScope rcpp_rngScope_gen;
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< unsigned int >::type n(nSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< Gluint& >::type tex(texSEXP);
    gl_gen_textures(n, tex);
    return R_NilValue;
END_RCPP
}
```

Comment: It is not a topic for a one-line answer.  Which is why we wrote an entire vignette about the topic which has been shipping with Rcpp for probably eight or nine years.

Comment: Are you referring to the [Rcpp-modules](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-modules.pdf) vignette?

Comment: No [Rcpp-extending](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-extending.pdf) is closer to what you need.

Comment: Non-intrusive extension via `RCPP_EXPOSED_AS`?